# Add workflow rule criteria to update checkbox if text field was last edited more than 6 months ago

Tags: workflow, custom-field, visual-workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I need to check last edited date as part of rule criteria on a custom field.

I need the workflow rule to check when the field was last populated - if it was updated (with text) more than 6 months ago a checkbox will need to be selected automatically. I'm ok with the last bit - I just don't know what criteria/ options to select for the first bit - does SF record when the field was populated?

**EDIT:** Added the following rule:

```
AND(NOT( ISBLANK( general_note__c ) ),ISCHANGED( general_note__c ))
```

but still cant work out how to add the 6 months criteria to it...

Comment: How many fields do you need to do this for?

Comment: why don't you use time trigger WF here?

Comment: just one field (field type textfield)

Comment: @TusharSharma - good point but there is no option to select the field I need - it just shows 'contact - last modified date' I just need this trigger to run if 'field1__c' contains text that hasn't been modified in the last 6 months (180 days)

Comment: you can do something like IsChanged(field1__c) then run after 180 days.

Comment: Given it's only for one field, I think you're best off creating a dateTime field to store the last modified date of that field in it.  Then you can run workflow/validation off that field.

Comment: @TusharSharma - that sounds like a good idea - so basically I add IsChanged(field1__c) to the rule criteria and a field update to 'uncheck' the checkbox field associated with it? Is that correct? Nick - I am trying to avoid creating extra fields for the time being but will if i need to...!

Comment: user - you'll have to create an additional field to track the last time the field was changed.  Which in turn means anytime you do your updates you'll also have to update the time/date field.  You'll check for:

Comment: ... continuation of last comment:  You'll check for:

isChange(field1) && (Now() - TimeDate_Field_4_field1__c) > 180)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional field to track the last time the field was changed, **Time/date update Field 1**.  Anytime Field1__c is changed you'll need to update the corresponding **Time/date update Field 1**.

When you do your check for field1, you'll need to include the time/date field.  Therefore check for:

isChange(field1) && (Now() - Time/date update Field 1) > 180)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using time trigger actions in workflow. Whenever the text field is changed you can add a time trigger to update the checkbox to True with time as "Trigger Date + 6 Months". So that, this action will be scheduled to execute at 6 months later. Meanwhile, if any user changes the text field, then salesforce will automatically removes the existing scheduled action and will create new one. So that, your checkbox will be be updated to True after 6 months if text field value is not changed.

Comment: I cannot use the Time-Dependent Workflow Actions because my evaluation criteria is set to 'Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited'! If I change it to 'created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria' it says I cannot use the ISCHANGED function when using this rule...! I am really stuck now!